What’s the elevator pitch for our site?
From The 7 Essential Questions of Every Beta, one thing we should decide on is what the elevator pitch for our site should be.

4. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?
Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one
floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The
elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is
about. Every word counts!
Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

the tagline the motto
the blurb under the logo
a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
perhaps eventually the domain name in some form


Please provide only one elevator pitch per answer so that others can vote for each individual pitch. If you have multiple elevator pitches to provide, please answer the question multiple times.

Cgnotiive Seicnce: it wroks bthices

How that joke works: http://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/cmabridge/

A more succinct variant of Josh Gitlin's:
The Cognitive Science Stack Exchange is a place for scientific discussion of the mind.
This implies that the discussion is scientific and thus objective. It says that the discussion is on the mind, instead of listing specific fields. The naming for fields related to the mind is so convoluted and contradictory, I don't think listing specific ones is wise. 
Mine doesn't refer to the fact that the community is about questions and answers, but I don't think it needs to. In the space of one sentence, I don't think the concept can be conveyed very well. And, when someone visits the site the format of the discussion will become clear anyway.
I think it's important for the statement to be inclusive, rather than exclusive. Attracting people of a scientific persuasion who are interested in the mind should be the goal of this sentence. The specifics can be sorted out later.

+1, I like this better than mine!

I'm going to go ahead and just throw something out as a starting point:
Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange is a place for those who study the mind to exchange information about objective questions related to psychology, psychiatry and cognitive sciences.
I'm not loving it. It's wordy. It's a bit cumbersome. But I think it conveys our topic, the fact that it's for objective questions, and that it's a site for experts.
But it's a starting point. Anyone's welcome to take it and improve upon it!

Variant (1): "Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange: Where you can find and share answers to scientific questions in the cognitive sciences, including psychology, psychiatry, and cognitive science"

That's a definite improvement over mine @JeromyAnglim! Please feel free to post that as a separate answer if you like.


What have scientists found out about our brains till now and what do we know that we don't know?
How to objectively think about the human mind-- ask the scientists.

P.S: Feel free to edit and improve

Maybe something like: 

The Cognitive Science Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for scientific discussion of the mind.

or 

The CogSci Stack Exchange is a forum for the scientific discussion of the human mind.

Basically, any variance of these or the one I built these of off, thanks Preece, seem to be able to get the job done. Almost everyone knows what Q&A stands for, but "forum" may help keep the atmosphere a bit more on the refined, academic side of things. 
I think pointing out that this is predominantly about humans may be helpful to some extent, but that is debatable of course. Shortening it to cogsci will help folks remember the current url, and would make a good domain name in the future. In fact, with a quick check cogsci.in is available. As well cogsciqa.com/org/etc is open. 

My concern about this is that we're really not about discussion, that's too subjective. We're about objective questions and answers...

"The CogSci Exchange is a forum for scientific inquiry about the human mind."

Brains, using them to study them.
